# Reading Excel with some Borders missing

Tags: java, excel

I am reading a .xslx file using Apache POI in Java.The last row in it is having some borders missing around some cells.
when I am reading this then in the last row after reading "abc"(written in first cell) ,am directly reading "rule1"(written in third cell) and second column is empty and bottom border is missing for it.

So the value of second cell which is empty cell is lost.So how can I be able to know that whether I have skipped any cell due to this formatting problem?

Comment: What does `Cell.getColumnIndex()` return for the "second" cell (which should be the third)? Else I only can see handling cell groups in the sheet itself. There are three methods for that: `addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress region)`, `getNumMergedRegions()`, and `getMergedRegion(int index)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggession,Cell.getColumnIndex Solved the problem.

Comment: Then I will make it an answer that you can accept. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Cell.getColumnIndex()` to retrieve the current cell's index. With this information you will be able to exactly get its position, and thus also find out whether there were any groups.